# How to add another RibbonGroup in RibbonTab of outlook add-in

Tags: outlook-addin, office-addins

I am creating a custom ribbon as outlook add-in. Using VS2015 I added a new Add-In project.On adding a new Ribbon from 'Add new item' menu, I get a ribbon group default created. I can add more controls in this group. But I am not able to add more ribbon groups in the same ribbon tab. For example :

[image]

just like Outlook has more than one group in every tab

[image]

I see no option in Tab's properties to add a new group.Then how can I achieve this?

Comment: I am having the same problem.  I went to View > Toolbox and dragged an Office Ribbon Controls > Group over to the ribbon

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is possible to add multiple groups.
[image]

I am using visual studio 2015. I will recommend to use Ribbon xml for designing VSTO. You need to make unique id for each control.

Comment: Thanks. I was using the visual designer and then I am getting no option to one more group. Can I mix both xml and visual designer for creating the Ribbon?

Comment: No,but I sent screenshot using designer of Visual studio  part

Comment: Got that, Thanks

Comment: It's a given that it's possible. This answer doesn't say how though.